# BuildContext in a Flutter BLoC class

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

In short, does the `context` belong in the BLoC class and if it doesn't, what's the right approach?

I'm using a `Provider` as an abstraction layer between the Firebase DB and the UI. Recently, we've been abstracting further away to use the BLoC pattern, so that the widgets don't manipulate the data in the `Provider` directly. It's all proceeding nicely, but due to the fact that we use both the providers and the BLoC, I am not sure how to use the `BuildContext` properly, as the context ha more to do with the Widgets/UI than the business logic.

Here's an example:

```
class SomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final SomeWidgetBloc bloc;
  
  SomeWidget({Key key, this.bloc});
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => StreamBuilder(stream: bloc.getSomeData, 
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Text(snapshot.data ?? "Empty");
     }
}

class SomeWidgetBloc {
  BuildContext context; // should it be here? Currently, it's needed for the Provider
  
  SomeWidgetBloc(BuildContext context);
  
  Stream<String> get getSomeData {
     return Provider.of<SomeFirebaseProvider>(context).fetchSomeData();
  } 
}
```

Comment: keep context in bloc classes is really bad idea

Comment: This is the bad part of the provider, you need the context for everything, your "presenter" or bloc should not contain the context of your view.
That is why git_It is a better option for Service Locator.

Comment: use https://pub.dev/packages/injectable/ It is one of the best options for DI. Don't use plain get_it

Comment: injectable is overcomplicated and redundant, just use plain getit

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your `SomeFirebaseProvider` instance to the `SomeWidgetBloc` constructor at creation time.